# How to draw multi line graph using phpGraphlib

Tags: php, html, phpgraphlib

I have successfully created a line graph using phpGraphlib. But I don't get any idea how to draw a multiline graph using this library . The x-y values are stored in arrays here. My  code is here

```
<?php
    include("phpgraphlib.php");
    $graph=new PHPGraphLib(1000,1000); 
    include("db_connect.php"); 
    $dataArray=array();
    $graph_array=array();
    $sql="SELECT name,mark1,mark2, entered_time FROM student ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con) ;
    if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $without_comma_value=explode(',', $row['mark1']);
    $count=count($without_comma_value);

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
    $Val_onebyone= $without_comma_value[$i];
    $num=$i+1;
    $dataArray[$num]=$Val_onebyone; 
     } 

    }
    }

  $graph->setBackgroundColor("#F78181");
  $graph->addData($graph_array);
  $graph->setBars(false);
  $graph->setLine(true);
  $graph->setupYAxis(20, 'black');
  $graph->setupXAxis(20, 'black');
  $graph->setTextColor('black');
  $graph->setDataPoints(true);
  $graph->setDataPointColor('maroon');
  $graph->setLineColor('maroon');
  $graph->createGraph();
   ?>
```

It plots a graph with mark1 values. I want to show mark2 values too. How it is possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
include('phpgraphlib.php');
$graph = new PHPGraphLib(650,200);
$dataX = range(1, 15);
$dataY1 = array();
$dataY2 = array();
foreach($dataX as $x => $y)
{
    $dataY1[$x] = rand(-10, 10);
    $dataY2[$x] = rand(-10, 10);    
}
$graph->addData($dataY1, $dataY2);
$graph->setDataPointColor('red');
$graph->setLineColor('red', 'blue');
$graph->setBars(false);
$graph->setLine(true);
$graph->setDataPoints(true);
$graph->createGraph();
```

Result (line color can be different, but color of datapoints stays the same)
[image]